# Property facet Nullable = None is overridden in Model.edmx xml on Update Model from Database

Tags: entity-framework, n-tier-architecture, edmx, updatemodel, facet

Using Entity Framework 6, I need to maintain a property facet value when using the Model wizard to update.

My property is not nullable in the database, but I have my property facet set as Nullable = None, and my model facet set as Update Property Facets = False. I have to manually edit the Model.edmx file to remove the Nullable="false" attribute from the property. The solution builds successfully in this state. The problem is when I do an Update Model from Database, the Model.edmx file adds back the Nullable="false" attribute and when I build I receive the error that "Error 3031: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 999:Non-nullable column COLUMN_NAME in table TABLE_NAME is mapped to a nullable entity property."

How do I prevent the Model.edmx from adding the Nullable="false" attribute when running the Model wizard?

This is related to issue [Designer: No way to mark facets of entity properties not to be overriden by database facets](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/706)  but slightly different.

I think this is an EF issue, but please note that we are using the NTier Entity Framework ([NTIER](https://ntieref.codeplex.com))

@ChristofSenn Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue with no fix in the near future, as referenced on CodePlex.   [Property facet Nullable = None is overridden in Model.edmx on Update Model from Database](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2489)